# Castle Windsor Auto registration with constructor parameters

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

```
public abstract class BattleVehicle : IVehicle {
  public BattleVehicle (IList<IGuns> someGuns, ISolider driver) { /*...*/ }
}
public class BigAssTank : BattleVehicle, ITank { /*...*/ }
public class AngryBirdsAPC : BattleVehicle, IAPC { /*...*/ }
//and a lot more of these battle vehicles ....
```

Now, say by standard, I want each battle vehicle to register 2 pistols `List<Pistols> twoPistols` and a `Rookie : ISolider` as a default driver. How do I do this?

I was expecting something like:

```
container.Register(Classes
                  .FromAssemblyContaining<IVehicle>()
                  .BasedOn<IVehicle>()
                  .DependsOn(new {someGuns = twoPistols, driver = rookie}) //won't work here....
```

Of course this won't work. I only found a rather old post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686801/castle-windsor-auto-register-types-that-have-dependency-in-constructor) from '09. I am not sure what is the right way to fluently register all the concrete Vehicles now. Please help and/or link me to any advanced auto registration tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Configure` extension method. Usage:

```
container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyContaining<IVehicle>()
        .BasedOn<IVehicle>()
        .Configure(k => 
            k.DependsOn(new {someGuns = twoPistols, driver = rookie})))
```